# Jersey Client with Apache connector for pooling (performance)

Tags: java, jersey, apache-httpclient-4.x

We have a jersey client, with the basic config:

```
public class HttpClient {

    private transient final WebTarget target;

    public HttpClient(final String host, final int port, final String path, final int requestTimeout) {
        final URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://" + host).port(port).build();
        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, requestTimeout);
        target = client.target(uri).path(path);
    }

    public byte[] makeRequest(final byte[] request) throws HsmException {
        try {
            return target.request()
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM), byte[].class);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Box JAX-RS exceptions as they get weirdly handled by the outer Jersey layer.
            throw new Exception("Could not make request: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, with that client, we manage to make around 900 requests per second. So in my attempt to get better results I thought about implementing pooling, using Apache Http client with the jersey connector, like this:

```
public class HttpClient {
    private transient final WebTarget target;

    public HttpClient(final String host, final int port, final String path, final int requestTimeout) {
        final ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, requestTimeout);
        clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 500);

        final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(150);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(40);
        connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(new HttpHost(host)), 80);

        clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager);

        final ApacheConnectorProvider connector = new ApacheConnectorProvider();
        clientConfig.connectorProvider(connector);

        final URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://" + host).port(port).build();
        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
        target = client.target(uri).path(path);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] makeRequest(final byte[] request) throws HsmException {
        try {
            return target.request()
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .post(Entity.entity(command, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM), byte[].class);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Box JAX-RS exceptions as they get weirdly handled by the outer Jersey layer.
            throw new Exception("Could not make request:" + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the results are exactly the same, about 900 requests per second.

I am not being limited by CPU, ram, disk, etc. I can't find the bottleneck. I tested multiple values when setting the connection manager but with the exact same results.

Am I missing something? Are there any other parameters I am missing? Am I using this the wrong way?

Comment: use wireshark to examine the request headers and src/dst ports to see if you're actually using keep-alive connections and reusing connections. If you're on a headless server, use tcpdump to take the capture, then export it to your windows box and look at the pcap file with wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

You can try HTTP connection pooling with httpasyncclient instead.

The httpclient uses thread-blocking I/O for connection pool, which means that the thread responsible for sending the HTTP request is also responsible for handling the HTTP response as well. In the meantime, the thread remains blocked on the socket.

In contrast, the httpasyncclient is a fully asynchronous HTTP client side handler based on the Java NIO (non-blocking) I/O model which allows library users to stream message content from a non-blocking HTTP connection.